# Testing URLs - URLs that don't exist return 200

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a function to test my URLs which looks like this:

```
def test_URLs(self):

    routes = [
    'about/',
    'archive/',
    'index/',
    'admin/',
    ''
    'doesntExist/'
    ]

    for route in routes:
        response = self.client.get(route)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

and my URL patterns which looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #CMS url
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'core.views.index'),
    url(r'^index/', 'core.views.index'),
    url(r'about/', 'core.views.about'),
    url(r'^archive/', 'core.views.archive'),
    url(r'^talks/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'core.views.getTalk'),
```

In my test_URLs function, the route 'doesntExist/' doesn't exist, rather aptly. When I run my server and try to access `doesntExist/` I get the log message

`[04/Oct/2013 09:37:40] "GET /doesntExist/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2629`

So `doesntExist/` definitely doesn't exist yet when I run the above test I get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.017s

OK
```

Why does my test think it exists?

Comment: It really depends a lot on the code in `self.client.get`, but the URL `doesntExist/`, without any hostname at the front, would conceivably fall foul of your ISP "trying to be helpful". Its DNS server might resolve the non-existent hostname `doesntExist` to its own search page.

Comment: Interesting. I've tried doing `end_point = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + route` and getting the response of that but I'm still getting the same problem. How could I get around this?

Comment: What does the `print self.client.get('/doesntExist/').content` prints?

Comment: Try putting `'/'` at the front of all the urls in `routes`.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin It gives me the markup for what appears to be my Amazon S3 bucket

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I was using an app called [Lockdown](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-lockdown/src). Status codes where being returned as 200 because it was getting the login HTML form which is displayed no matter what the URL is if a user hasn't logged in before.

Simply don't use Lockdown whenever you're testing.